# jQuery: manipulate multiple dynamically select created with same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble manipulating multiple select inputs on my form..
Basically I add some fields(car brands) with same class name by a button, so in my select input I choose a brand and with jQuery I get the models for that brand, but when I have multiple selects it changes all my car models select inputs because it has the same name.
Here is my code:

```
$(".marca_r_1").on("change", function(e){
  if(event.target.value != null){
    $.get("/administracion/marcas-modelos/"+event.target.value+"",function(response){
      target = $('.modelo_r_1')
      console.log(target)
      if(response.length > 0){
        target.empty();
        for(i=0; i<response.length; i++){
          target.append("<option value='"+response[i].id+"'>"+response[i].modelo+"</option>");
        }
      } else {
        target.empty();
        target.append("<option value='#'>No se encontraron resultados..</option");
      }  
    });
  }
});
```

How can I prevent this problem with jQuery?

**EDIT:** I put my html code (I'm working with Laravel):

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label("marca_r","Marca: ",["class"=>"control-label"]) !!}
                {!! Form::select("marca_r[]",$marcas,null,["class"=>"form-control marca_r_1","placeholder"=>"Ingrese la marca del repuesto","required"]) !!}<br/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label("modelo_r","Modelo: ",["class"=>"control-label"]) !!}
                {!! Form::select("modelo_r[]",array(),null,["class"=>"form-control modelo_r_1","placeholder"=>"Seleccione un modelo..","required"]) !!}<br/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label("vin_r","VIN: ",["class"=>"control-label"]) !!}
                {!! Form::text("vin_r[]",null,["class"=>"form-control vin_r_1","placeholder"=>"Ingrese el VIN del repuesto","min"=>5]) !!}<br/>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

And I add new fields dynamically with that same class names by a button

Comment: Can you post your html because here you need to find target in relation to the currently changed select element.

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue when you declare "target" since you get all tags with the class modelo_r_1.

Try something like :

```
$(".marca_r_1").on("change", function(e){
  if(event.target.value != null){
    (function(target,value){
      $.get("/administracion/marcas-modelos/"+value+"",function(response){
        console.log(target)
       if(response.length > 0){
           target.empty();
           for(i=0; i<response.length; i++){
               target.append("<option value='"+response[i].id+"'>"+response[i].modelo+"</option>");
           }
         } else {
           target.empty();
           target.append("<option value='#'>No se encontraron resultados..</option");
         }  
       });
   })($(this),event.target.value);
  }
});
```